# How to get information about the zoomed part of the image in OpenCV window?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am using `OpenCV` built with `Qt` support to use zoom functionality in the window. Now I want to know what part of the image has been zoomed in my code. For example, to get the coordinates of the upper-left pixel, image dimensions, and use them in my code. Is there any way to do such thing?

OpenCV image showing window with expanded GUI:
[image: OpenCV image showing window with expanded GUI]